# My script file doesn't run when I drop my file into chrome even though my html and css run perfectly

Tags: javascript, css, html

My html and script files are linked and my text editor (webstorm) says it is linked. It even runs when I copy the code into code pen. It even runs when I enter them into the code snippet here. However, when I drop the file into chrome, my JS doesn't run even though my html and css run perfectly. What is wrong? Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "SUP!";
}
```

```css
#test {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     color: white;
     font-size: 20px;
     background-color: red;
     margin: 20px;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     position: absolute;
 }


.bg {
    background-image: url("white.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.above-nav {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: "dancing Script", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.naver {
    background-color: #EEE7E1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: sticky;

}

.naver a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;

}

.naver a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.foot {
    margin-top: 650px;
    background-color: #EEE7E1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: sticky;
    opacity: .6;

}

.foot a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
}

/* ALL CSS ABOVE THIS LINE IS FOR THE HOMEPAGE */

.bg-pic {
    background-image: url("white.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.above-nav-pics {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: "dancing Script", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.naver-pics {
    background-color: #EEE7E1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: sticky;

}

.naver-pics a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;

}

.naver-pics a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.foot-pic {
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: #EEE7E1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: sticky;
    opacity: .6;

}

.foot-pic a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
}

.dating-header {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Didot, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;

}

.proposal-header {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Didot, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;

}

.engagements-header {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Didot, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;

}

.sub-head-pics {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Didot, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.col {
    margin: auto 30px;
    position: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.col img {
    width: 240px;
    height: 330px;
    padding: 20px 50px;

}

/* ALL CSS ABOVE THIS LINE IS FOR THE PICTURES PAGE */

.bg-story {
    background-image: url("w+n133 2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.naver-story {
    background-color: #EEE7E1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: sticky;
    opacity: .9;

}

.naver-story a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;

}

.naver-story a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.head-story {
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Didot, sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}
.story-options {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;

}

.story-options a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}
.story-options a:hover {
    color: black;
}
.foot-story {
    margin-top: 680px;
    background-color: #EEE7E1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: sticky;
    opacity: .8;

}

.foot-story a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #604F55;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
    <title>The Carr Family</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../assets/img/june.jpg" type="image/jpg" sizes="any">
    <link href="../assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../assets/css/whit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<button id ="test" onclick="myFunction2()">Hello</button>


<div class="bg">
    <h1 class="above-nav">Nathaniel Wesley & Whitney Jane</h1>
    <nav class="naver">

        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="pictures.html" target="_blank">Pictures</a>
        <a href="story.html" target="_blank">Our Story</a>
    </nav>

    <footer class="foot">
        <a href="#">&copy The Carr Family | </a>
        <a href="#">June 22, 2018</a>
    </footer>
</div>


<script src="/scripts/main.js">

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use the debugging tools available in Chrome to look at your Network tab and console to make sure you're not getting any errors.

Comment: `/scripts/main.js`? Try placing your script inside `C:\scripts\main.js`!

Comment: I could be completely mistaken on this, but I was under the impression unless you are running something like MAMP WAMP XAMPP your computer won't natively run php or js. If I'm wrong on this please correct me.

Comment: You can run your debugger tools by F12 and then look at error details in console

Answer (score 0):

Your script is pointed to `/scripts/` while your CSS is pointed to `../assets/`. Try using a relative path (starting with `./` or `../`) for your script, instead of an absolute path.